# How to call functions with API calls in an action using Redux-hooks useDispatch from component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm doing a project using redux-hooks, I m new to redux-hooks. I am having actions.js file having different API call function. and to dispatch the action from a component using useDispatch(). do I have to import every function from actions.js to my different component to dispatch the action? or any methods are there? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Before react-redux incorporated hooks into their library it was typical to split the parts of redux into their own container file. There you would map the actions and state that you needed into props that you would pass into the component. For example containers and components would look something like this.

Container `Example.js`:

```
// Node Modules
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

// Actions
import {action1, action2} from '../actions';

// Components
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';

// Actions
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  action1: () => dispatch(action1()),
  action2: () => dispatch(action2()),
});

// State
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state1: state.example.state1,
  state2: state.example.state2,
});

export const Example = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExampleComponent);
```

Component `ExampleComponent.jsx`:

```
// Node Modules
import React from 'react';

const Example = (props) => (
  <div>
    <label>{props.state1}</label>
    <label>{props.state1}</label>
    <button onClick={props.action1}>Action 1</button>
    <button onClick={props.action2}>Action 2</button>
  </div>
);

export default Example;
```

Although you could write both the container and component elements together in one file, this is just an example of how Redux could be used within React. With the introduction of hooks into `react-redux` you can now access the Redux store through their provided hooks.

Component `ExampleComponent.jsx`:

```
// Node Modules
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

// Actions
import {action1, action2} from '../actions';

const Example = (props) => {
  // Dispatch
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Redux State
  const state1 = useSelector((state) => state.example.state1);
  const state2 = useSelector((state) => state.example.state2);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{state1}</label>
      <label>{state1}</label>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(action1())}>Action 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(action2())}>Action 2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

With this method you can import your component directly from the `ExampleComponent.jsx` file instead of having to import it through a container. For your actions, you only need to import what you need to use for the component and wrap it with the `dispatch` hook that `react-redux` provides.

Comment: If I have to call more than 5 actions in components, Is there any way like using mapdispatchtoprops and actioncreators to bind them as props or I have to import all the action methods in components?

Comment: You could `import * as Actions from '../actions';` and reference them as `Action.action1()` or `Action.action2()` when you need them.

Comment: @ppak10 How we can call async action using dispatch?

Comment: @Ganpat Redux does not support async actions out of the box and you will have to use some [middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) such as redux-thunk to make it work

Comment: @ppak10 Thanks, now I'm using redux-thunk and calling like `dispatch(action1()).then(response => {console.log(response)}, error => {console.log(error)})` for api call. Assume action1() is async-await function which return response after web api call.